# Could an integral w.r.t a local martingale be a proper martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

The following is taken from *"Stochastic differential equations and diffusion processes"* by Ikeda & Watanabe.

> Let $Y,X\in \mathcal M_2^{c,loc}$ (the space of continuous, square
>   integrable, local-martingales).
>
> If we define $\tilde{Y}$ by
>
> $$ \tilde{Y}(t)=Y(t)-\langle Y,X\rangle_t,$$
>
> Then $\tilde{Y}(t)$ is a local martingale.

Proof:

Assume first that $\tilde{Y}(t)$ is bounded in the sense that for each $t\geq 0$, $\tilde{Y}(t)\in \mathfrak L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

By Ito's formula we have

$$d(M(t)\tilde{Y}(t))=\tilde{Y}(t)dM(t)+M(t)dY(t)$$

where $M(t)$ is the Doléans-Dade exponential of $X$ (we assume that $X$ satisfy the Novikov's condition and hence M(t) is a martingale).

At this point the author say that this implies that $M(t)\tilde{Y}(t)$ is a martingale, shouldn't it be a *local*-martingale?

We have that $$M(t)\tilde{Y}(t)=\int_0^t \tilde{Y}(t)dM(t)+\int_0^t M(t)dY(t)$$

We have that the first stochastic  integral is a martingale  since the integrand is bounded and the integrator is a square integrable martingale, now on the second stochastic integral we are integrating wrt a local martingale, I don't see how the martingale property could arise.

Do the author actually mean *local*-martingale or is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: hey @saz! you can find it at the very end of page 177, on the proof of theorem IV.4.1.

Comment: I see; thanks..